# First-class functions in JavaScript and function declarations in C++

Tags: javascript, c++

I am coming from a little C++ background but would like to understand functions in JavaScript. My questions are in bold.

In C++, function declarations and definitions are different. What I gather is that in JavaScript is called a function declaration is what is in C++ a function definition and thus C++-style function declarations don't exist in JavaScript. **Is this correct?**

I tried a C++-style function declaration like this in JavaScript:

```
function randomFunction(arg1, arg2);
```

and got an error:

```
function randomFunction(arg1, arg2);
                                   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'
```

Now, if in JavaScript, first-class functions mean that functions can be treated as variables why can't we write functions like :

```
function randomFunction(arg1, arg2);
```

**but we can do this?**

```
let var1;
```

It doesn't seem like functions are like variables in this case. **What am I missing?**

It appears to me that with `let var1`, JavaScript doesn't know how much space to allocate and this would be similar with a function declaration in C++. **Is it because of function hoisting that function declarations aren't needed?**

I may be misunderstanding both C++ and JavaScript and would appreciate some clarification.

Comment: Functions are like variables in the sense that you could do something like
`let myFunction;   myFunction = function (arg1, arg2){....};`  It doesn't have forward declarations like c++

Comment: @Ron, yes, they are unrelated but comparing and contrasting them helps clarify their individual strengths and unique features. It has helped with human languages too.

Answer (score 1):

A definition does both, it declares the function (make the signature known) and defines it (provides the implementation). In JavaScript you don't have a separate declaration because you have hoisting, in C++ you need a separate declaration, in some cases because the function is not known/cannot be used before it is declared.

Named functions are like variables because you can change to what the name of the function refers, and it defines a scope for that name:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict"
  function randomFunction(arg1, arg2) {}

  randomFunction = 1;
  console.log(randomFunction)
})()
```

So the way how you can use the function name `randomFunction` is similar to `randomFunction` being a variable:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict"
  var randomFunction = function(arg1, arg2) {}

  randomFunction = 1;
  console.log(randomFunction)
})()
```

Comment: I don't understand the last phrase, "So regarding ..." and the 2nd code snippet, which looks similar to the 1st.

Comment: @heretoinfinity `function randomFunction(arg1, arg2) {}` defines a function with the name  `randomFunction`, but in contrast to c++ `randomFunction`behaves like a variable in JavaScript, so you can change what value `randomFunction`  holds.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it. I needed to get coffee.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare a statically typed compiled language to a very dynamic interpreted one. You cannot *define* a function in JavaScript, because variables can hold values of any type (functions are just objects are just values), whereas in C++ the type of the value that a variable holds (an identifier refers to) has to be known for compilation.

```
 var randomFunction = 1; // the variable holds a value of type number

 randomFunction = function(arg1, arg2) { // now it holds a value of type object (function)
   //...
 };
```

*function declaration*s in JavaScript are just another way of declaring a variable and assigning the function to it. This happens when the environment record gets initialized (before any other code runs), this is known as *hoisting*:

```
 test();
 function test() { }
 // barely equals
 var test = function test() { };
 test();
```

Comment: Could you explain what I should expect from the 2nd code snippet? I understand the 1st

Comment: @geretoinfinity it is supposed to show what hoisting and function declarations are.

Comment: What do you mean by "barely equals"?